# Issue in sending data to the server on openvpn

Tags: linux, docker, sockets, networking, openvpn

I have the following socket programming code. My client program is running on a VM on desktop machine using virtual box and my server program is running on a University cluster VM. The client is unable to send the data to the server. Both client and server program are running inside a docker container

running client and server container

```
docker run --rm -it -p 192.168.56.110:5555:5555  client bash

docker run --rm -it -p 192.168.101.238:5555:5555  server bash
```

client.py

```
context=zmq.Context()
print("Connecting")
socket=context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://192.168.101.238:5555")
name="Max"
while True:
  message=input("Message: ")
  socket.send_pyobj({1:[name,message]})
  message2=socket.recv_pyobj()
  print("%s:%s" %(message2.get (1)[0], message2.get(1)[1]))
```

server.py

```
context=zmq.Context()
socket=context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:5555")
while True:
  message=socket.recv_pyobj()
  print("%s:%s" %(message.get(1)[0],message.get(1)[1]))
  socket.send_pyobj({1:[message.get(1)[0],message.get(1)[1]]})
```

ip route client VM

```
 default via 172.27.248.1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
 default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp metric 100 
 10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100 
 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto static scope link metric 100 
 143.117.101.145 via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto static metric 100 
 169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s8 scope link metric 1000 
 172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
 172.18.0.0/16 dev br-1f684a10d7c8 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
 172.27.248.0/22 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.250.80 metric 50 
 192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.56.110
```

server ip route

```
default via 192.168.101.254 dev ens160 proto dhcp src 192.168.101.238 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
192.168.101.0/24 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.101.238 
192.168.101.254 dev ens160 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.101.238 metric 100
```

On the client side, its stuck its not sending the data to the server and on the server its not receiving data.

Help is highly appreciated thanks